# Java get superclass method to use subclass instance method when called by subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am attempting to get a superclass method to run on subclass methods/fields when called by the subclass. For instance

```
public class CoffeeMachine() {
    protected int cost = 3;

    protected int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}

public class FancyCoffeeMachine() extends CoffeeMachine{
    protected int cost = 6;
}

main{
    FancyCoffeeMachine expensive = new FancyCoffeeMachine();
    System.out.println(expensive.getCost());
}
```

I would like this to print 6, but it prints 3 instead. I want to make this as DRY as possible, so I am trying to avoid making a second getCost() method. Is there any way to do this? How can I get a superclass method to use subclass variables, when called by the subclass? The same thing happens with methods: if I have

```
public class makeCoffee() {
    System.out.println("Coffee cost " + this.getCost());
}
```

the output will be "Coffee cost 3" even when I call makeCoffee on a FancyCoffeeMachine. Why is this? How can I fix it? Or is there a better way to implement this object structure that completely circumvents this mistake?

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question. You are asking about using overridden instance *fields,* not methods.

Answer (score 2):

Linking fields does not use dynamic dispatch as virtual method calls do. Your field `FancyCoffeeMachine.cost` simply *hides* the field `CoffeeMachine.cost`.

To achieve what you want (i.e. FancyCoffeeMachine having a higher cost) you can simply set a new value to the `CoffeeMachine.cost` field within an initializer block or constructor in `FancyCoffeeMachine`.

```java
public class CoffeeMachine {
    protected int cost = 3;

    protected int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
public class FancyCoffeeMachine extends CoffeeMachine{
    {cost = 6;} // <- sets CoffeeMachine.cost
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have to override `getCost()` on `FancyCoffeeMachine` too.

```
public class FancyCoffeeMachine() extends CoffeeMachine{
    protected int cost = 6;

    protected int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

But If I wanted to implement this what I would do is make CoffeeMachine abstract like this

```
abstract class CoffeeMachine {
    private int cost;

    CoffeeMachine(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

and then extend it on my superclass like this

```
class FancyCoffeeMachine extends CoffeeMachine {
    FancyCoffeeMachine(int cost) {
        super(cost);
    }
}
```

and call it as such

```
FancyCoffeeMachine fancyCoffeeMachine =  new FancyCoffeeMachine(6);
System.out.println(fancyCoffeeMachine.getCost());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling method `getCost` from superclass(CoffeeMachine) because you don't have it in your subclass(FancyCoffeeMachine). And your superclass doesn't know anything about subclass and its field `cost`. You should also override method `getCost` to get it working like you described.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally redefine a protected field like `cost` in a subclass. Instead, you would give the subclass a way to set the cost while constructing the object. Look at this:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static class CoffeeMachine {
        protected int cost;

        public CoffeeMachine() {
            this(3);
        }

        protected CoffeeMachine(int aCost) {
            cost = aCost;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public static class FancyCoffeeMachine extends CoffeeMachine{
        public FancyCoffeeMachine() {
            super(6);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("plain: %d\n", new CoffeeMachine().getCost());
        System.out.printf("fancy: %d\n", new FancyCoffeeMachine().getCost());
    }
}
```

(Don't worry about the fact the two `CoffeeMachine` classes are declared static. That's just so they can all be defined in one file.)

The base class `CoffeeMachine` has two constructors:

1. A protected constructor which accepts a cost as an argument.
2. A public constructor which sets the cost to 3.

The subclass `FancyCoffeeMachine` calls the protected superclass constructor with a cost of 6. So the `cost` variable is set to 6 and `getCost()` will return that value when you run it:

```
plain: 3
fancy: 6
```